# Bash script header for virtual machine

Tags: bash, security, terminal

I have a little compiler pet project that generates bytecode for a virtual machine. To run the generated bytecode from the terminal I would always have to invoke the virtual machine with the generated bytecode file (by `svm my-binary-file`, where `svm` is the name of the VM executable). Because I want to be able to directly execute the file generated by the compiler, I came up with the following solution:

I prepend a few bash commands to the generated file that identify the filename (to account for the user renaming the file), invoke the virtual machine with that file and exit. These are the commands:

```
# Identify directory
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
# Identify filename
FILENAME="$(basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")"
# Invoke the virtual machine
svm "$SCRIPT_DIR/$FILENAME"
# And exit
exit $1
HERE COMES BINARY JIBBERISH...
```

The comments above each command are important because the VM needs them to skip past the bash commands to the binary section. The compiler invokes `chmod +x <filename>` to permit execution of the file.

Now I can directly run the generated file with `./my-binary-file`. This all works wonderfully, but here is my question:

Since I know nothing about bash and I'm not very versed with unix and the terminal (I had to google all the commands and basically copied them from SO), I wonder if there are any obvious pitfalls or security problems with this solution that I am not aware of. After all this solution feels very hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it works or not depends entirely on the initial interpreter. It's hacky, yes, but anything else would necessarily be a very OS-specific solution.

If Bash doesn't mind the script ending with garbage, this is fine. Such methods used to be common in Tcl scripts, which would sometimes start like a bash script that executes tclsh (instead of directly calling tclsh, for various reasons).

(Similar techniques are also part of the language in Perl and PHP, where the entire script is parsed but you can explicitly tell the compiler to stop at `__DATA__` – although in this case, the original interpreter *is* Perl or PHP, it merely reads a data payload from the script.)

What would make it less hacky is to directly use `"$0"` instead of trying to split it up and recombine. You don't need to go out of your way to resolve symlinks, usually.

A somewhat preferred mechanism for **Linux** specifically would be to register your format via 'binfmt_misc'. Make sure the executables begin with a distinct "magic number" of your choice (that is, a static prefix that unambiguously identifies your format; generally at least 4 bytes is a good idea) – teach your VM runtime to recognize and skip it if necessary, like it currently skips the `#!/bin/bash` – then you can configure Linux to accept such files as executables and to automatically run them under the correct interpreter.

For example, WASM executable files start with the bytes `\0asm\1\0\0\0`, so if you write this

```
:wasm1:M::\x00\x61\x73\x6d\x01\x00\x00\x00::/usr/bin/wasmer_wrapper:
```

to `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register` (or place it in `/etc/binfmt.d/wasm.conf`), now you can directly execute WASM programs:

```
$ ls -l main.wasm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 users 1.2K Feb  8  2023 main.wasm*

$ file main.wasm
main.wasm: WebAssembly (wasm) binary module version 0x1 (MVP)

$ head -c 16 main.wasm | hd
00000000  00 61 73 6d 01 00 00 00  01 17 04 60 01 7f 00 60  |.asm.......`...`|

$ ./main.wasm 
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is reassuring to here I'm not the only one to come up with this solution. Will definitely directly use `$0` to invoke the VM. Are there any bash implementations though that mind if the script ends in garbage? If not this seems like a less intrusive solution than to register a custom binary format

Comment: There's only one Bash implementation: Bash itself. Other shells are not Bash; most of them (including Bash) are Bourne/POSIX shell implementations with their own extensions, but they do not usually have any further "reimplementations" with the same name. So if you have `#!/bin/sh` you'll get _something_ POSIX/Bourne-compatible (which may or may not work), but if you have `#!/bin/bash`, it will always be Bash specifically. That said, at least the Tcl trick of `#!/bin/sh ... exec tclsh "$0"` used to be compatible with generic Bourne sh (as it even predates the widespread support of #! in Unix).

Comment: Okay, I think I'm confident now to go with this solution. But just to make sure I understand correctly: If I write `#!/bin/bash` on the first line, the script will always be run by Bash and work correctly. But if there is no Bash installed on the system the script will not run. If I write `#!/bin/sh` the system will choose any interpreter and depending on that interpreter the script may be rejected because of the garbage bytes in the end of the file?

Comment: Generally yes, although 1) the system doesn't just choose "any" interpreter, it's always whatever 'sh' your distribution has chosen to provide at /bin/sh; 2) realistically, no, I don't think there is *any* sh interpreter that would care – they all read scripts line by line, as far as I've seen. It's only the non-shell language interpreters that tend to parse everything upfront.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. It's good to hear you think no interpreter will care about the garbage bytes. Again thank you so much for your help!! :)

Comment: Specifically, no interpreter that you'd find at /bin/sh. It *might* even be that this behavior is codified in POSIX, but I didn't check. And come to think of it, this is actually how many of those downloadable Linux installers work (e.g. the "Nvidia driver" `*.run` files) – they literally consist of a shell script plus a tarball appended...